# How do I have more edits in a year then I do in all of time?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, caching

When I look here: https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=year&search=neal it says that I have made `483` edits.

When I click on [the "all" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all&search=neal) it says I've only made `482` edits.

How is that possible?

Comment: Caching? I see 483 for both.

Comment: @PopularDemand hmmm i see 483 for both now too. odd, shouldnt they both come from the same database?

Comment: They do, except some pages are more heavily cached then others, the home page being an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are caches at play here, some for different lengths and hit/cached initially at different times...so you'll see some slight *temporary* differences here and there.  This is acceptable for us given the massive performance benefit, so this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Answer (score 1):

I know that those pages use a cached value, as they are not immediately changed when you edit another posts. I guess it is caused from how the pages are cached, as I read the same value in both the tabs.