# (Meta Only) Tag Synonym (bugs, bug-reports) -> bug

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, retag-request, synonym-request

It would seem that one person, and perhaps more in the future have used the [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs) tag where [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) should have been used.  Likewise the same thing has happened with [bug-reports](/questions/tagged/bug-reports); it too should be synonymic.

For just one post, as it was [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110724/how-do-i-have-more-edits-in-a-year-then-i-do-in-all-of-time) it was trivial enough for me to edit out the duplicate synonymous tag, but I still think the tag synonym should be made to help prevent mis-use in such a way in the future.

Comment: At this rate you're going to hit the monthly question limit in like 3 days

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me, wouldn't bother me either.  I'll just go back to telling people why their copypasted "Hello World"s don't work as expected.  :)  I didn't know there was a limit though, good to know.  Is there a better way to request synonyms?

Comment: I'm not sure if it exists on meta or it's just Stack Overflow; I don't know that anyone's ever asked enough questions here to find out

Comment: I will find out!  I have a LOT more tags to request the merger of...